# Weight represented with decimal, need to show as just numbers, php

Tags: php

I have the weight grabbed from an xml as 0.800, I want to convert it to 000008. This Eg. 003456 is 345.6 kilograms shows how it is to be represented for heavier weights, could someone give me a heads up as to where I could start with this one?

thanks!

EDIT: I have the solution but does anyone know why it cuts off the last digit? See below:

XML:

```
<GROSSWEIGHT>345.800</GROSSWEIGHT>
```

PHP:

```
$LINE_WEIGHT = ($shipment->COLLO->GROSSWEIGHT*10); // 6 CHARS
sprintf("%06s", $LINE_WEIGHT)
// output 003450
```

EDIT: If i follow this, it works:

```
echo str_pad(0.800*10, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
// output 000008
```

AS SOON as I include xml data:

```
echo $shipment->COLLO->GROSSWEIGHT; // 345.800
echo str_pad($shipment->COLLO->GROSSWEIGHT*10, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
// output 003450
```

Please see pic below:

[image]

Comment: `printf("%06d", $grossweight*10);`

Comment: does not work dude...

Comment: Well then your XML data is probably in UTF.

Comment: how do I fix this? I've narrowed the issue down to when I * 10, it removes the last digit.....

Comment: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php I wager that the decimal in your string data is not an ASCII decimal, so PHP's implicit conversion fails there.

Comment: I'm wagering that you're a FKING GENIUS. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

use `*10` and then "pad-left":

```
echo str_pad(0.800*10, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //000008
echo str_pad(345.6*10, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //003456
```

Comment: this works partly, it does not show the decimal... weird... I get 000000 and 003450??

Comment: added in utf8_decode(string), everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You'd first need to multiply by 10, then have a look at `sprintf`, especially the padding option.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question to how I decided to go ahead coding. I used the sprintf solution suggested by simon as it seems a lot cleaner.

XML:

```
GROSSWEIGHT>0.800</GROSSWEIGHT>
```

PHP:

```
$LINE_WEIGHT = (utf8_decode($shipment->COLLO->GROSSWEIGHT)*10); // 6 CHARS
sprintf("%06d", $LINE_WEIGHT);
```

Thanks everyone!